# Example of embedding arbitrary data / text into a contract to be sent to another account?

Tags: contract-design, whisper

Since users can create smart contracts, can't someone just embed plain text into the smart contract and then have that sent to another user in effect making it a messaging system? and how much would each message cost per byte?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible and quite simple, but not necessarily advisable.
Some things to keep in mind:

1. All messages need to be encrypted off-chain. Otherwise anyone can read all of your communication
2. Storage is expensive. It's not incredibly cost-prohibitive, but users would need to buy ether and keep their accounts funded. Costs can be reduced by using [Events](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=events#events) instead of storage.
3. [Whisper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-Overview) is a messaging system based on the Ethereum p2p protocol that would be more suited to this application. It is separate from the blockchain and does not require Ether.